# TikZ - Why is the outer line of the grid way more bright than the grid itself?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

Why does the outer line of the triangle grid (= the dark gray one) look so much more bright? It seems to get the same colour when I change `draw=gray` to `draw=black`, but that doesn't make much sense to me (yet). Could someone explain please?

**Picture with draw=gray**

[image]

**Picture with draw=black**

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
tikz,
relsize,
amsmath
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


%% from here on forth TikZ-stuff

\usetikzlibrary{
calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,
decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,
matrix,shapes.symbols,patterns,intersections,fit
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\tikzset{
>=latex
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
%N
\draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (9,6);
%
\draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (9.5,0) node[anchor=west]{Input};
\draw[->,thick] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6.5) node[anchor=south]{Output}; 
%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} \draw [thick](\x cm,-2pt) -- (\x cm,2pt);
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y);
%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} \draw (\x cm, 0 cm) node[anchor=north]{\x};
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,6}  \draw (0 cm, \y cm) node[anchor=east]{\y};
\draw
(2,1) coordinate (A)
(3,3) coordinate (B)
(3,2) coordinate (C)
(4,3) coordinate (D)
(5,4) coordinate (E)
(5,2) coordinate (F)
(6,3) coordinate (G)
(8,5) coordinate (H)
;
%%Cone
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer}
\draw[draw=gray,fill=gray,pattern=grid,draw opacity=0.6,fill opacity=0.6] (F) -- ($(F) + (-3.5,0)$) -- ($(F) + (0,3.5)$) -- cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}
%%Labels + Circles
\foreach \pt/\labpos in {A/below right,B/below right,C/below right,D/below right,E/below right,F/below right,G/below right,H/below right}{
        \filldraw (\pt) circle(2pt) node[\labpos=3pt,fill=white]{\pt};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The outer line of the light gray grid or the dark gray grid?

Comment: Good call. Sorry. Meant the dark gray grid => the triangle. I'll edit the op.

Comment: It all looks the same to me or at least I can't tell there is a difference.

Comment: Hm, weird. Added a picture for `draw=black` to the op. Both snapshots were taken with 6400% zoom in Adobe Reader XI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't set `draw opacity=0.6`: That will make black lines appear gray, and gray lines appear in a lighter shade of gray, because the white paper shines through. The `draw` color isn't applied to the grid pattern, its color is still black, which is why it appears as a darker gray than the outline.

To get both the grid and the outline in the same shade of gray, simply set `draw=gray, pattern color=gray` (without `draw opacity=0.6`):

[image]

```
\documentclass[
11pt
]{standalone}

\usepackage{
tikz,
amsmath
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}


%% from here on forth TikZ-stuff

\usetikzlibrary{
calc,trees,shadows,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,
decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,
matrix,shapes.symbols,patterns,intersections,fit
}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background layer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground layer}
\pgfsetlayers{background layer,main,foreground layer}

\tikzset{
>=latex
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
%N
\draw[style=help lines,step=0.5cm] (0,0) grid (9,6);
%
\draw[->,thick] (-0.1,0) -- (9.5,0) node[anchor=west]{Input};
\draw[->,thick] (0,-0.1) -- (0,6.5) node[anchor=south]{Output}; 
%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} \draw [thick](\x cm,-2pt) -- (\x cm,2pt);
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,6} \draw [thick](-2pt,\y) -- (2pt,\y);
%
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} \draw (\x cm, 0 cm) node[anchor=north]{\x};
\foreach \y in {0,1,...,6}  \draw (0 cm, \y cm) node[anchor=east]{\y};
\draw
(2,1) coordinate (A)
(3,3) coordinate (B)
(3,2) coordinate (C)
(4,3) coordinate (D)
(5,4) coordinate (E)
(5,2) coordinate (F)
(6,3) coordinate (G)
(8,5) coordinate (H)
;
%%Cone
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background layer}
\draw[draw=gray,fill=gray,pattern=grid,pattern color=gray] (F) -- ($(F) + (-3.5,0)$) -- ($(F) + (0,3.5)$) -- cycle;
\end{pgfonlayer}
%%Labels + Circles
\foreach \pt/\labpos in {A/below right,B/below right,C/below right,D/below right,E/below right,F/below right,G/below right,H/below right}{
        \filldraw (\pt) circle(2pt) node[\labpos=3pt,fill=white]{\pt};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your MWE contains the correct code `pattern color=gray`, your code bit in the text still says `fill color=gray` btw.

Comment: @henry: Oh yeah, sorry! Corrected now.